# POST request failing silently

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I'm trying to send a POST request using the requests module for Python. However, when I send the POST request, I receive the page of the form; the redirect is ignored.

Specifically, the page is http://www.adm.uwaterloo.ca/infocour/CIR/SA/under.html, and I'm running the following (I isolated the problem to these lines of code):

```
from requests import post

param = {"sess" : '1151',
         "subject" : 'CS',
         "cournum" : 136,
         "level" : 'under'}

req = post("http://www.adm.uwaterloo.ca/infocour/CIR/SA/under.html", 
       data=param)

print req.text
```

Any help solving this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The URL you are posting to is incorrect, see form's `action` points to a different one:

```
<form method="POST" action="/cgi-bin/cgiwrap/infocour/salook.pl">
    ...
</form>
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> import requests
>>> 
>>> param = {"sess" : '1151',
...          "subject" : 'CS',
...          "cournum" : 136,
...          "level" : 'under'}
>>> 
>>> req = requests.post('http://www.adm.uwaterloo.ca/cgi-bin/cgiwrap/infocour/salook.pl', data=param)
>>> print BeautifulSoup(req.content).title.text

Returning Query Info
```

Comment: My bad, this is new to me - I thought you were supposed to send the POST request to the first page. Thanks!